# How to format a TimeSpan for hours not days

Tags: c#, silverlight, formatting, timespan

The following code

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:%h} hours {0:%m} minutes", 
                   new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerDay));
```

produces this output:

> 0 hours 0 minutes

What I would like is this output:

> 24 hours 0 minutes

What am I missing in this format string?

P.S. I know that I could manually bust up the TimeSpan into days and hours, and multiply the two but would rather use a custom format string, as these timespans are being displayed in a silverlight datagrid and people are expecting to see horus, not days.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx), using `%h` will show you

> The number of whole hours in the time interval that **are not counted as part of days**.

I think you will need to use the `TotalHours` property of the `TimeSpan` class like:

```
TimeSpan day= new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerDay);
Console.WriteLine("{0} hours {1} minutes", (int)day.TotalHours, day.Minutes);
```

---

**Update**

If you absolutely need to be able to achieve the stated format by passing custom formatters to the `ToString` method, you will probably need to create your own `CustomTimeSpan` class. Unfortunately, you cannot inherit from a `struct`, so you will have to build it from the ground up.

Comment: Thanks for the update --- that's what's pushed me over the edge towards a custom type.

Comment: you might have to truncate it otherwise totalhours property won't show the right figure.

Dim x As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 3600)
String.Format("{0}hr:{1}min", CInt(Math.Truncate(x.TotalHours)), x.Minutes)

Answer (score 10):

There doesn't seem to be a format option for getting the total hours out of a `TimeSpan`. Your best bet would be to use the [`TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property instead:

```
var mySpan = new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerDay);
Console.WriteLine("{0} hours {1} minutes", (int)mySpan.TotalHours, mySpan.Minutes);
```

`TotalHours` returns a double as it includes the fractional hours so you need to truncate it to just the integer part.

Comment: Right, as I said I know I can bust up the timespan, but what I don't think I can do with this approach is format the timespan with a formatstring passed into it's ToString Method.

Comment: @Ralph - yes you are "busting up" the `TimeSpan` but there's no multiplication needed.

Comment: @ChrisF -- true enough, TotalHours is easier than Days*24+Hours, but the difficulty remains. I need a format string. --- and I'm guessing that it's not possible.

Comment: you might have to truncate it otherwise totalhours property won't show the right figure.

Dim x As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 3600)
String.Format("{0}hr:{1}min", CInt(Math.Truncate(x.TotalHours)), x.Minutes)

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is:

```
TimeSpan day = new TimeSpan(2,1,20,0); // 2.01:20:00
Console.WriteLine("{0} hours {1} minutes", (int)day.TotalHours, day.Minutes);
```

Console will show:

> 49 hours 20 minutes